# How do you check syscall for x86_64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I can't find a dedicated official website to search for such information .

For example,if I want to do `exit`,how should I do it with `syscall` introduced in x86_64?

Any manual for this kind of details?

I'm on Centos.

Comment: Take a look at [PDFs here](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/). (They're kind of big..)

Comment: @Mehrdad ,according to this article,it seems intel's pdf won't help for specific distributions,it finally depends on OS's implementation: http://www.thexploit.com/secdev/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls/

Comment: Some parts of it do help, some parts of it don't. Specifically, the *numbers* are OS-specific, but the *calling convention* should be very similar.

Comment: @Mehrdad ,I'm seeking exact info as I need to code it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glibc [**`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S`**](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S), see if this helps.

Comment: N Fetissov,why the syscall number in `%rax` in overwritten when entry?

Comment: N Fetissov,`movq %rdi, %rax         /* Syscall number -> rax.  */` ,can you explain this one?

Comment: `%rdi` is the first function argument in C x86_64 calling convention (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions), `%rax` is the input to the kernel. Does that make it clear?

Comment: N Fetissov ,so that's the implementation for `syscall()` API in C,right?

Answer (score 1):

Let the C library do it for you:

```
movl $0, %rdi  # or whatever exit code you want (0-127)
call _exit
```

You *really* do not want to make system calls yourself.  The C library insulates you from a bunch of low-level ABI issues (many system calls exist in more than one version, depending on exactly which kernel you have; some of them don't require an actual trap into supervisor mode; etc), it knows how to set `errno`, and it will pick the most efficient trap sequence for the architecture and kernel version.