# How to compile assembly whose entry point is not main with gcc?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

```
.text
    .globl _start
_start:
     pushq %rbp
     movq %rsp,%rbp
     movq $2, %rax
     leaveq
     retq
```

I'm compiling with `-nostdlib`:

```
[root@ test]# gcc -nostdlib -Wall minimal.S &&./a.out 
Segmentation fault
```

What's wrong here?

BTW,is it possible to make the entry point other names than `main` and `_start`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @jaquadro mentions, you can specify the entry point on the command line to the linker (or use a link script): `gcc -Wall -Wextra -nostdlib -Wl,-eMyEntry minimal.S && ./a.out`

The reason your program segfaults is, that since you're not using the standard library there is nowhere to return back to (`retq`). Instead call exit using the correct syscall (in this case it is 60, which is put into `rax`, the first (and only) parameter is put into `rdi`.

Example:

```
.text
.globl MyEntry
MyEntry:
    # Use Syscall 60 (exit) to exit with error code 42
    movq $60, %rax
    movq $42, %rdi
    syscall
```

[Related question on how to perform syscalls on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537828/how-do-you-check-syscall-for-x86-64)

Comment: btw,by experiment I find `retq` and `ret` the same function,is that true?

Comment: In this case, yes. The _q_ is a [size suffix](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Operation_Suffixes) and the default size in x86_64 so it's probably superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the entry point by passing an option to the linker

http://sca.uwaterloo.ca/coldfire/gcc-doc/docs/ld_24.html

To do this with gcc, you would do something like...

```
gcc all_my_other_gcc_commands -Wl,-e,start_symbol
```

main is different, it is not the entry point to your compiled application, although it is the function that will be called from the entry point.  The entry point itself, if you're compiling C or C++ code, is defined in something like Start.S deep in the source tree of glibc, and is platform-dependent.  If you're programming straight assembly, I don't know what actually goes on.

Comment: @je-rog Check the command again, I had a typo in an option (-Wl vs. -W).  My disclaimer is I've done all this with C code and my hope is that at least the entry option should still be relevant.  -Wl is intended to pass through options to the linker.

Comment: It's still not valid,maybe you can try it out.

Comment: @je-rog I appologize for being rusty with my syntax, I've updated again, and I've tested it this time.  It's very picky.