# How set set entry point in a elf target using ld script

Tags: c, gcc, elf

I want to specify the entry point to my ELF file using the linker script. I already defined some sections in my ELF, so want to set an entry point also withit. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Related: C level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097825/is-there-a-gcc-compiler-linker-option-to-change-the-name-of-main , assembly level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563663/how-to-compile-assembly-whose-entry-point-is-not-main-with-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a special (GNU) linker script command that sets entry point to given symbol's address `ENTRY(symbol)`. Refer to [official documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Entry-Point.html#Entry-Point).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the command line argument `-e entryName` is the way to go about it. A `man ld` should give you a heads up as well.

Answer (score 0):

First get the current linker script to a file with:

```
ld --verbose a.o | sed '/======/,/======/!d;//d' > myscript
```

Here we filtered the lines between `=====`, as mentioned at: [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w)

Then edit the `ENTRY(_start)` line to your desired symbol.

Finally use `-T` to select the custom script:

```
ld --verbose -T myscript a.o
```